# We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email. (getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty)

Tags: magento-2.1, installation

I'm using the theme - http://magento2.flytheme.net/themes/sm_furnicom/french/#

I purchased the theme from themeforest and had been trying to set up the application newly on the VPS. After I run the installer successfully, I get the following error on the home page "**We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email.**".

var/log/exception.log displays the following error

main.CRITICAL: exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: **getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/wwwbookmaniaco/public_html/dev/vendor/magento/framework/Image/Adapter/AbstractAdapter.php on line 304**'